# Why is ImageDataGenerator() performing poorly?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a image classification model, using ImageDataGenerator(). 
It seems that the model trains and performs poorly. The training loss stays at around 15 and the accuracy is barely 10%, the validation is about the same.

Just to see what would happen, I tried training without using the ImageDataGenerator() and set up the data in a similar way. It performed much better in training, validation and testing. With training loss of 0.71 and accuracy of 75% and validation loss of 0.8 and accuracy of 72%.

I need to figure out this model with the data generator because I will be moving on to a larger dataset, where it will not fit into memory.

So, I guess my question is what am I doing wrong with the ImageDataGenerator() that it is performing so badly and how can I improve the outcome?

When setting up the files (in all Train, Test, Validation folders), there are the classes with its own folder and in those folders is where the images are.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
IMG_SIZE = 100
train_it = data_gen.flow_from_directory('D:/.../Train/', class_mode='sparse',
                                       target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),color_mode='grayscale', shuffle=True,batch_size=32)
val_it = data_gen.flow_from_directory('D:/.../Validation/', class_mode='sparse',
                                     target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),color_mode='grayscale', shuffle=True,batch_size=32)

IMAGE_SIZE = [100, 100]

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(len(train_it.class_indices), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_it, epochs=20, validation_data=val_it )
```

Here is my code without ImageDataGenerator():
SETUP the data, using OpenCV

```
DATADIR='D:\...\Train'
CATEGORIES = pickle.load(open("CATEGORIES.p" , "rb"))
print(len(CATEGORIES))
IMG_SIZE = 100
training_data=[]

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except:
                print(category)
                print(img)

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data)

X=[]
y=[]
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X=np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
X=X/255.0
```

MODEL SETUP:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=[*IMAGE_SIZE, 1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(len(CATEGORIES), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y, epochs=20, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: You are using the same 'data_gen' object for both training and validation datasets.  Try instantiate a 2nd ImageDataGenerator for validation.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try and give you an update!

Comment: @jkjung13 Unfortunately it didn't help the loss or accuracy.

Comment: @jkjung13 Let me know if you have anymore insight. Thanks'

Comment: With your updated code, I'm not able to identify where the problem could be.  What I'd suggest is to grab a few batches of data from your data iterator ('train_it'), plot them, and make sure they are as expected.  You could refer to my code and blog post below for how to do that.  Code example: https://github.com/jkjung-avt/keras-cats-dogs-tutorial/blob/master/visualize_crops.ipynb.  Blog post: https://jkjung-avt.github.io/keras-image-cropping/.

Comment: @jkjung13 Thanks! I will give that a go and see what happens.

Comment: @jkjung13 I plotted them and they seem fine, so I am not sure what is happening. I am trying to find some answers, but it seems like everything is how it should be, so I am not sure what more I can do. Do you know of another way to train with large datasets?

Comment: My "keras-cats-dogs-tutorial" repository (https://github.com/jkjung-avt/keras-cats-dogs-tutorial) demonstrates exactly how to use Keras' ImageDataGenerator to train CNNs.  Maybe you could start with that code, plug in your data first, and then replace the model with your own.

Comment: @jkjung13 Okay Thanks I will try that! I tried using the cat and dog dataset with my code to see what would happen, and it did not perform well at all and the outcome was the same as my dataset. So I think there is definitely something wrong with the code. I will try using your code and hopefully that will solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @jkjung13 I made a dumb mistake. I didn't normalize the data by dividing by 255 and that was the issue. The cat and dog dataset is performing as it should now, so hopefully it is the same issue for my dataset too. So far, the training is going well and it passed the 10% for accuracy and loss is at 3 and continually going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@acho,

Mentioning the solution to this issue cited by you in the comments, for the benefit of the community.

Reason for the issue is that Input Data is not Normalized by dividing each Pixel Value by 255. It has an impact on Training because of the reasons mentioned below:

1. It converts Pixel Values from Integers to Float, in a range of 0.0-1.0 where 0.0 means 0 (0x00) and 1.0 means 255 (0xFF). Conv Nets work better on Float Values compared to Integer Values, and by normalizing it in a range of 0-1, computations will be reduced.
2. Normalization will help you to remove distortions caused by lights and shadows in an image.